# With Backbone.js & Rails, how do I correctly bind multiple collection updates to a view that renders updated select options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I am new to using Backbone.js and my Javascript/CoffeeScript-fu could use some attention.  I

I have a nested resource page (i.e., /network/:network_id/affiliation/new) with elements that need to load dynamically.  I thought this could be a suitable point to work with Backbone.js.

The start of my code is included below.  Here is what I am looking to accomplish on the page:

1. By default, a select list is populated with instances of Course from /courses.  The Rails view loads this by default, so I don't think anything needs to be done here.
2. A button that, when clicked, empties the select list and populates it with the JSON from /courses
3. A button that, when clicked, empties the select list and populates it with the JSON from /networks/:network_id/courses where :network_id is available as @network.id.
4. A button that, when clicked, empties the select list and populates it with the JSON from /metro_areas/:metro_area_id/courses where :metro_area_id is available as @network.metro_area_id.
5. A select list full of metro areas that, when selected, empties the courses select list and populates it with the JSON from /metro_areas/:metro_area_id/courses where :metro_area_id corresponds to the selected metro area.

   1. When a course is selected from the course select list, an anchor href is updated with that course's

(** Couldn't get the code to format properly, so here's a gist **)

https://gist.github.com/1d746b1f2e159b313149

Answer (score 1):

You can use embeded collections in model

```
class app.Network extends Backbone.Model

  url: ->
    base = "networks"
    return base  if @isNew()
    base + (if base.charAt(base.length - 1) is "/" then "" else "/") + @id

  initialize: ->
    @courses = new app.Courses(@get('courses'))
    @courses.url = '/networks/' + @get('id') + '/courses'

  getCourses: ->
    @courses
```